# How to get node attributes on context menu jstree

Tags: javascript, jquery, jstree

I want to be able to pass the node id to another php script but somehow I cannot get the id or other attributes of the node. Here is my code:

```
              "action": function (data) { 
                    if (confirm("Are you sure you wish to delete the selected item?")) {
                        var ref = $.jstree.reference(data.reference);
                        sel = ref.get_selected();
                        if (!sel.length) { return false; }
                        sel = sel[0];
                        alert($(sel).attr('id'));
                        $.get('response.php?action=delete_node', { 'id' : sel.parent, 'position' : sel.position, 'text' : sel.text })
                        .done(function (d) {
                            alert("node deleted.");
                            sel = ref.delete_node(sel);
                        })
                        .fail(function () {
                            alert("node cannot be deleted.");
                            data.instance.refresh();
                        });
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know your tree，but I use this,I think the same;

```
.on("changed.jstree", function(e, li) {
     var elm = $('li#' + li.selected[0]);
     alert(elm.attr('id'));
 });
```